# CalendarView does not work in fragments? Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

So if I create a new project and throw a calanderView into the xml file for the main activity. Then write some code in the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CalendarView mCalendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCalendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date =  year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth;
                Log.wtf("wtf","onSelectedDayChange" + date);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The setOnDateChangeListener will work as expected and Log.wtf will execute.

If I try to throw a calanderView into a xml file for a fragment. The calendar will appear in the fragment and I can click on dates. But for some reason the setOnDateChangeListener does not work. Here is my code for my fragment. Sorry its the default code so there is kind of a lot. I am new to using fragments so I am not sure whats all important. I implemented the setOnDateChangeListener in the onCreateView method.

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ThirdFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ThirdFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ThirdFragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private CalendarView mCalendarView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
        mCalendarView = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date =  year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth;
                Log.wtf("wtf","onSelectedDayChange" + date);
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I honestly have no idea why this does not work because I have other fragments in my project where I have buttons where the button click event works and I implemented those like this:

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // IMPORTANT this interface can send stuff back to the main activity
               mListener.register();
           }
        });
        return view;
}
```

If anyone could give me some insight it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the same `view` object which you have inflated in `onCreateView` method. Modify your `onCreateView` method like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
        mCalendarView = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date =  year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth;
                Log.wtf("wtf","onSelectedDayChange" + date);
            }
        });

        return view;  //instead of inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Fragments, if you're not using **binding** then in **onCreateView** method you should only `inflate and return the view`.. And do your code stuff in **onViewCreated** as `it makes sure that your get the inflated view and the view is not null`.

You should also look for **Fragment Lifecycle Methods**.
That way you'll understand how Fragments works along with Activity.